# Is there a python webframework which is able to run decently on 128mb of ram?

Tags: python, linux, webserver, web-frameworks, vps

I have a small and easy project with no DB interactions for which I don't have free resources except the small linux VPS (vServer) 128MB RAM machine. Feeling adventures  I want to try to implement this project in python.

Will it be possible? If so what setup (webserver, framework and so on) I have to choose?

I'm reading files from file-system and displaying their content in a beautiful way. Also diffs between the files and couple of similar things... No file upload from the users, all textfiles are pre-made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with a micro framework like [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) or [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Edit: You probably don't want to use django if you are looking for light. Django is a full stack framework and if you don't need database interaction I would seriously look into one of the above CherryPy or web.py.

Honestly I think that you should go with [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/). It is a single file and its memory usage is [very low](http://nuald.blogspot.com/2011/08/web-application-framework-comparison-by.html).

This will allow you to have python and bottle installed and you can read those files easily and serve content with bottle easily and with very low memory use.

Like I said before web.py, CherryPy, Flask are also good alternatives.

Comment: Is there any data of their memory usage?

Comment: It depends on the webserver, not on the webframework, correct?
So I can program my app with django and deploy it behind CherryPy somehow, can't I?

Comment: memory usage is also dependent on what you are doing.  What backend/storage you use if any.  How much templating, (what sort of template engine etc..).  Helloworld.py will use a lot more memory than a online commerce site ;-)

Comment: Bobo http://bobo.digicool.com/ is probably even lighter ;-) 

It provides 2 features:

Mapping URLs to objects
Calling objects to generate HTTP responses
It doesn’t have a templateing language, a database integration layer, or a number of other features that can be provided by WSGI middle-ware or application-specific libraries.

Comment: I think Flask actually uses as much memory as Django

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering your question, but if you have no DB interactions, why use Python at all? I think I would prefer to serve a site that does the expensive work on the client (since you are resource-restrained), i.e. with a light web server and neat Javscript framework. There are many, I like [angular.js](http://angularjs.org/).

Comment: Can someone at least explain the point to me how advising to use the wrong tech on the wrong platform will help anyone.